Program bypasses file security settings
I'm trying to block a website with the hosts file, so programs need to be able to read the file for the blocking to work. Editing the file is easy. The blocking works just fine at first. Then when I open this program, it edits the file and comments out the website I'm trying to block.
On the C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc folder, I changed the permissions so only Everyone exists on it. It's got an allow for the read and a deny for write. I made sure files in the folder are inheriting these permissions and only these permissions. I also tried this on just the hosts file but decided to go a level up because it wasn't working. Proc mon records the program doing the edit, even though no accounts should have write access.



Now, I fixed this by giving the hosts file a read only attribute, but I fail to see why what I did above didn't work. With just the readonly attribute, the file is safe. Even if Everyone has full control over the hosts file... Anyone have an explanation?
The program does NOT have elevated privs

What program are you talking about? It is generally known that you should not ever modify permissions on system files. You break things when you do that.

Only a program that had elevated permissions could edit the hosts file. So launch the program without those permissions. The hosts file is a HORRIBLE way to block a website. You probably should use DNS content filtering

@music2myear - Editing the permissions on the folder was for a test. The original editing of the permissions on the host file were very limited and non impactful to everything else. Putting everyone as a permission on it was purely to eliminate any doubts that the permissions were wrong. EVERYONE had deny for write on the file and the folder, yet the program could write to it.

@Ramhound Program wasn't started as an admin. No elevated permissions. This program is installed on a VM that goes through a VPN so I can't simply use my pi-hole to block it. Even if I could configure the vpn to use the pihole i wouldn't want risk requests going out from my IP.

Program is Internet Download Manager btw. You can install the trial version and if you have "127.0.0.1 www.internetdownloadmanager.com" in your host file, when you start the program up it gets commented out regardless of file permissions.  Well, as long as it has read permissions it will do it, but without read permissions chrome can't read the file so i have to leave read permissions enabled.

This is apparently a known behavior of IDM. This is from 4 years ago. I concur with others on that thread: Either you have a malicious copy of this, or this legit software behaves like malware. I suppose a third option is that you're trying to avoid paying fees by preventing the tool from checking its license, and we won't help you with that. https://www.reddit.com/r/Piracy/comments/f9yck1/how_to_prevent_hosts_file_from_being_changed/

@music2myear I am not asking for help on how to pirate the software.  I already figured out you can stop it from editing the file by marking it as read only and this is in my post. I intentionally left the program name out of the post because it isn't relevant to my question. I only supplied it in case someone wants to try reproducing it. I am asking this question because I don't understand how windows file securities can be bypassed like this.  I am an IT professional and windows is doing something I didn't think was possible, so I assume there is a gap in my knowledge.

@Migit - The only way IDM would be able to modify the hosts file is if its permissions were elevated to that of an Administrator. IDM cannot bypass the default permissions of that file, unless as part of the installation of the application, it’s required to change them. Which certainly is possible, I certainly won’t be testing IDM, to figure that out. If it requires an Administrators elevated permissions to install, then it might be unknowlingly be elevating it’s permissions. If that’s happening you wouldn’t be getting a UAC prompt.

I think evidence indicates that is not the case. IDM claims to do a lot of stuff, but it has also been around a long time as a download manager. Perhaps it installs a driver with additional privileges during installation. I would guess that it optimizes the system per its preferences as part of its "speeding up downloads 5x" claim, and part of that is to adjust the hosts file.

@Ramhound You can see which processes are elevated in task manager and IDM shows as not being elevated. I checked this like 5 times because I figured this would be the only way possible for it to do this.  If the program was calling some other program to do the edit, wouldn't that be the program that comes up as doing the edit in proc mon?  If idm is just calling a DLL to do the edit, that would have the same priv level as IDM.

My first thought was SeRestorePrivilege, but if it's not elevated... Is IDM a 32-bit program? System32 resolves to different physical locations for 32-bit and 64-bit programs. Do check the process token privileges using ProcExp or SysInformer, though?

The VMs I have don't require much memory so they are 32 bit versions of windows 10.
